# What type of test can be done in Android-Robotium

Tags: android, testing, robotium

An new to testing ,By using android Robotium what type of test can be done 
By using robtium can we test security testing 
Can any one help me

Answer (score 1):

I didn't performe that type of tests but Robotium is focused mainly in the UI automation tests.
I recommend you to visit [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Robotium/article.html) to get a first contact with the framework. There is also a recorder mode to make easy the test process [here](http://robotium.com/).